# Order Progress bar is broken when bootstrap is applied

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use this progress step wizard and it works fine but when i try to add the bootstrap css everything messes up and i dont know what is what is wrong.

Here is a js fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/gy2gqns1/

```css
.step-wizard {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.step-wizard .swprogress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
}
.step-wizard .swprogressbar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0aa89e;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid e5e6e6;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard .swprogressbar.swempty {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e5e6e6;
}
.step-wizard ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  left: -2%;
}
.step-wizard li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 24.7%;
}
.step-wizard li .swstep {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #e5e6e6;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard li .swtitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 20px;
  padding-top: 42px;
  color: #969c9c;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.6s ease;
  transition: color 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard li.swactive .swstep {
  border-color: #0aa89e;
}
.step-wizard li.swactive .swtitle {
  color: black;
}
.step-wizard li.swdone .swstep {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0aa89e;
  border-color: #0aa89e;
}
.step-wizard li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.step-wizard li > a:hover .swstep {
  border-color: #0aa89eg;
}
.step-wizard li > a:hover .swtitle {
  color: black;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .step-wizard li {
    width: 24%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .step-wizard li {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="step-wizard">
      <div class="swprogress">
        <div class="swprogressbar swempty"></div>
        <div id="prog" class="swprogressbar" style="width:33.3%"></div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="swactive">
          <a href="#" id="step1">
            <span class="swstep">1</span>
            <span class="swtitle">Client Details</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="swactive">
          <a href="#" id="step2">
            <span class="swstep">2</span>
            <span class="swtitle">Brand Details</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#" id="step3">
            <span class="swstep">3</span>
            <span class="swtitle">Shift Details</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#" id="step4">
            <span class="swstep">4</span>
            <span class="swtitle">Confirmation</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap adding son styling to ul ad other that override your style.
With little correction to your style you can correct the modify by bs:

```
.step-wizard {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.step-wizard .swprogress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
}
.step-wizard .swprogressbar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0aa89e;
  opacity: 0.4;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid e5e6e6;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard .swprogressbar.swempty {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e5e6e6;
}
.step-wizard ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  left: -2%;

  margin-top:16px; /* Style correction */
}
.step-wizard li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 24.7%;
}
.step-wizard li .swstep {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 38px;   /* Style correction */
  height: 38px;  /* Style correction */
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #e5e6e6;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease, border-color 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard li .swtitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 20px;
  padding-top: 42px;
  color: #969c9c;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.6s ease;
  transition: color 0.6s ease;
}
.step-wizard li.swactive .swstep {
  border-color: #0aa89e;
}
.step-wizard li.swactive .swtitle {
  color: black;
}
.step-wizard li.swdone .swstep {
  color: white;
  background-color: #0aa89e;
  border-color: #0aa89e;
}
.step-wizard li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.step-wizard li > a:hover .swstep {
  border-color: #0aa89eg;
}
.step-wizard li > a:hover .swtitle {
  color: black;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .step-wizard li {
    width: 24%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .step-wizard li { 
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```